# retrieve data from multiple table

Tags: php, laravel, select, model

I have two tables (users and roles) have one to one relationship 
*User model*

```
public function user_role()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
}
```

*the function in controller*

```
   public function update_role($id)
{

    $role = User::with('user_role')->find($id);
    return view('update_role') -> with ('role',$role);
}
```

*the update_user view*

```
{{$role -> name}}
{{$role -> setting}}
{{$role -> images}}
```

but the retrieved data is only the user name from user table and not retrieve the user setting and user images from roles table

Comment: What are you getting when you echo out the $role in the controller in the first place?

Comment: if I returned the $role show me all data from two tables according to id ,

Comment: when I echo $role in the controller I get all data from tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{{$role->user_role->name}}         //this is if you are getting the role name
{{$role->user_role->setting}}      //this is if you are getting the role setting
{{$role->user_role->images}}       //this is if you are getting the role images
```

*Updated 2015-11-23*

try to change the name of the variable in the controller so that it will have the right meaning when we bring it to the view, because you are bringing the user with user_role.

```
//controller
$user= User::with('user_role')->find($id);
return view('update_role') -> with ('user',$user);

//view - accessing it will be as simple as
Username {{$user->username}}<br>             //accessing column in your user table
Role     {{$user->user_role->name}}<br>      //accessing column in your user_role
Setting  {{$user->user_role->setting}}<br>
Image    {{$user->user_role->images}}
```

Comment: it work successfully with role table , but with user table  this is work {{$role->name}}

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are trying to access the user_role via eager loading from user? if yes, then use the one I pointed out. otherwise, can you please additional information so that I can see the problem?